# No route matches [POST] - Sending data to Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http-post

I'm trying to send data to my Ruby on Rails application via an AJAX POST request.
This works fine on the index page where it just accepts the POST request and takes the parameter for usage like `params[:MyParam]`, however when trying to do the **exact** same thing in my `show` action, I get the error:

> No route matches [POST]

I'm sending the POST request like so:

```
 <% if !params[:recData] %>
var PostDone = false;
 <% end %>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.post(document.URL, { recData: "POST REQUEST!" }, function(response) { 
  if(PostDone == false) {
    document.write(response);
    PostDone = true;
  }
  });
 });
```

I'm kind of new to AJAX and Rails, so a helping hand would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first of all if you read [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) you know that `resources :products` adds following route

```
Verb    Path    action  used for
POST  /products create  create a new product
```

also routes are matched from the top so since you have

```
resources :products # matches '/products' via POST
match '/products' => 'products#index', :via => :post
```

each time you have POST request to the `'/products'` first route defined with `resources :products` is matched

`show` action works because it is also defined with `resources :products` but only for GET method

now workarounds

change order to

```
match '/products' => 'products#index', :via => :post
resources :products # never matched '/products' via POST
```

or use `:except`

```
resources :products, :except => :create # does not match '/products' via POST
match '/products' => 'products#index', :via => :post
```

in both cases your `create` action will newer be matched

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `document.URL` in your `$.post` function with the actual URL you are posting to, e.g. inserting it via Rails like this:

```
$.post('<%= objects_path %>', ...
```

Of course replace `objects_path` with whatever your named route is called.

The reason you are getting the error is probably that the `index` and `create` actions have the same URL (only with a different HTTP verb), but the `show` action has a completely different one. In your jQuery you are always using the URL of the current page which just happens to work with the `index` action, but not on any other page.

Comment: If you can't figure out the named route, you can also specify it directly, e.g. `'/products'`, although I don't recommend it. What's important is that `document.URL` does not make sense there.

Comment: If the server doesn't register a request at all, you should examine the source and check for JavaScript errors first.

Comment: As I said, the `create` action with method `POST` has the same URL as the `index` action, i.e. they usually both have `'/products'`, but one of them with `GET`, the other one with `POST`.

Comment: There is no `create` form actually, I guess it's the `new` form you are referring to. Anyway, I would strongly suggest you read this guide and some of the others on this site before you go further: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Well if you know literally nothing about it, I suggest you try to learn about it before actually writing code, for example by reading the guides I mentioned. Even for Rails there is a certain minimum you need to know before you can do anything at all.